# Special characters and key names

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have the following model class:

```
class Test(db.Model):
   name = db.StringProperty()
```

I am supposed to use unique key names for each entity, so I can retrieve entities this way:

```
<input type="text" name="name" />

def post(self):
    key_name = self.request.get('name')
    entity = db.get_or_insert(key_name, name=key_name)
      # first key_name needs encoding?
```

How should I encode the key_name in order to allow for characters such as æ, ø, å and others in the html form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not really need to do anything special.
These characters are handled normally.

In case you wanted support for HTML special characters you would have to change it to:

```
cgi.escape(self.request.get('name'))
```

Comment: I'm sorry my bad. The problem is I would also like to be able to store "two words" as keynames but without the space in between, so this works: ../test/{{test.key.name}} (eg. ../test/two-words). I used urllib.quote for this but that's where the issue with special characters came in.

Comment: I guess I should just store the key name as "two words" and figure out a way to quote the url in the django template and then unquote it in the def post(self). Thanks!